# Leiningen keeps old defns

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have very strange Lein's behavior: it keeps loading unexisting old code.

There is `src` directory with something like `src/service/api.clj` and `src/user.clj`. All files under `src/service` are reloading, but lein totally ignores any changes in `src/user.clj`.

```
(ns user
  (:require [ragtime.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [ragtime.repl :as repl]))
...

(defn migrate []
  (repl/migrate (load-config)))
```

Even if I delete `migrate` definition, REPL will have it in `user` namespace, lein will run it with `lein run -m user/migrate` after doing `lein clean` and will not load changes with `(load-file "src/user.clj")` too.

How to make it load my changes to `user.clj` ?

Answer (score 0):

Lein only looks for code in source paths directories. If you don't have any specified then `src` is assumed. In your project.clj this would be the suggested entry:

```
:source-paths ["dev" "src"]
```

To be able to reload code from the REPL this will work for `user.clj`:

```
(ns user
  (:require [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer (refresh refresh-all)]
            [clojure.stacktrace]
            [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

;;
;; To run open a REPL and:
;; (reset)
;; (core/migrate)
;; Repeat those two commands after every source code change you make
;;
(defn reset []
  (refresh))
```

`user.clj` can go under the `dev` directory.

The answer to your question is I think that `user.clj` is supposed to be changed so infrequently that restarting the JVM/REPL is not an issue after you have made changes. Code that is being changed frequently should be under the `src` directory, and should not be named as namespace `user`. The *main* entry point code that you have typically goes in a file called `core.clj`. So you should put the contents of your `user.clj` file in the `core` namespace i.e. in a file called `core.clj`, which is placed under `src`.

Comment: `user` is a special namespace not suited for entry commands such as you have at `migrate`. Try renaming your `user` to `core`. That would be a more conventional approach.